# Adding a file name in the array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have this code that gets all file types. Then if it has the extensions in the array, it should be stored in the `excludedFile` array and will be displayed after execution.

```
Dim excludedFile() as String
Const exts = _
  ".ade.adp.app.asp.bas.bat.cer.chm.cmd.com.cpl.crt.csh.der.exe.fxp.gadget" & _
  ".hlp.hta.inf.ins.isp.its.js.jse.ksh.lnk.mad.maf.mag.mam.maq.mar.mas.mat"

Dim file As Variant
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)

ReDim data(1 To UBound(file) + 1, 1 To 1)

' filter the list
For i = LBound(file) To UBound(file)
  ext = LCase(Mid(file(i), InStrRev(file(i), ".")))
  If InStr(1, exts, ext & ".") = 0 Then  ' if not blacklisted
    count = count + 1
    data(count, 1) = file(i)
    Else 'I've tried this but returns Subscript out of range error
    excludedFile(UBound(excludedFile)) = file(i)
    ReDim Preserve excludedFile(1 To UBound(excludedFile) + 1) As String
    found = true
  End If
Next
if found then
     MsgBox Join(excludedFile, vbCrLf)
end if
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the rest of your Sub code ? it's missing the `excludedFile` declaration array. you also have a type error in `If InStr(1, exts, ext & ".") = 0 Then` should be `(1, ext, ext & ".")` no?

Comment: @ShaiRado Updated my question. And its not a typo :)

Comment: I must be missing something, you are opening a single file, so what array ? Do you have another loop above ? to get all files in a folder don;t you need to use the `GetFolder`  command?

Comment: @ShaiRado This is the line where I select files in a directory: `file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)`. Thanks

Comment: never mind, I saw you have your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but working

```
Const exts = _
  ".ade.adp.app.asp.bas.bat.cer.chm.cmd.com.cpl.crt.csh.der.exe.fxp.gadget" & _
  ".hlp.hta.inf.ins.isp.its.js.jse.ksh.lnk.mad.maf.mag.mam.maq.mar.mas.mat"


Dim file As Variant
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)

'Dim your Array and a Counter
Dim excludedFile() As String
Dim efCount As Integer

ReDim Data(1 To UBound(file) + 1, 1 To 1)

efCount = 0
' filter the list
For i = LBound(file) To UBound(file)
  ext = LCase(Mid(file(i), InStrRev(file(i), ".")))
  If InStr(1, exts, ext & ".") = 0 Then  ' if not blacklisted
    Count = Count + 1
    Data(Count, 1) = file(i)
    Else 'I've tried this but returns Subscript out of range error

    'Use counter to access array
    ReDim Preserve excludedFile(efCount)
    excludedFile(efCount) = file(i)
    efCount = efCount + 1

    found = True
  End If
Next

If found Then
     MsgBox Join(excludedFile, vbCrLf)
End If
```